# T-SQL - WHERE condition performance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I have variable declared like this

```
DECLARE @Customer_No VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Customer_No = 'Z110073574;Z110027464;Z110229752;Z110274156;Z110170566;Z110102837;Z110074199'
```

The query contains condition

```
WHERE ((@Customer_No = '') OR ([Customer No_] IN (SELECT [No_] FROM Customer)))
```

If the variable @Customer_No can contains blank value (''), filtering should be skipped. In case the variable contains customers separated by semicolons, the string is parsed into table Customer and the query is filtered by values in Customer table.

The query takes 15 minutes to run. If I use just the second condition, it takes about 50 seconds.

```
WHERE [Customer No_] IN (SELECT [No_] FROM Customer)
```

I don't get it. How is this possible? Any solution? Explanation?
Thank you.

Edit: Query

```
SELECT  DET.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]
      , DET.[Amount]
      , DET.[Entry Type]
      , CLE.[Document No_]
FROM [dbo].[Company$Cust_ Ledger Entry] CLE
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Company$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] DET ON CLE.[Entry No_] = DET.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]
WHERE ((@Customer_No = '') OR (DET.[Customer No_] IN (SELECT [No_] FROM Customer)))
  AND (DET.[Entry Type] = 1 OR DET.[Entry Type] = 2)
  AND (CLE.[Due Date] >= @FromDueDate AND CLE.[Due Date] <= @ToDueDate)
  AND CLE.[Posting Date] <= @ToDate
```

Comment: Is this a stored procedure?, how many rows are there in your table?. Can you show the execution plans?

Comment: Also, who names your columns? I'd love to introduce their wrists to my ruler.

Comment: DO you really need VARCHAR(max)

Comment: Ouch, the variable names get even worse!  I did not think it was possible!

Comment: Added code sample. @Aaron Bertrand These are default column names from MS Dynamics NAV database.

Comment: @Sparky Yes. Variable takes user input in SSRS. User can add much more customers to filter.

Comment: @Rutz If you are using SSRS, then you should be using a multi value parameter and use `[Customer No_] IN (@Customer_No)` instead of inserting those values on another table. That gives you the option of using `all` to select every value instead of worry about checking for `''` instead

Comment: Post query plans with and without {@Customer_No = '') OR}. A wild guess: skipping the select in is causing a full table scan. Not skipping it causes some filter to be applied (with help of a index) and reducing post filters/joins/lookups scope.

Comment: Well then the Dynamics folks definitely need to introduce their wrists to my ruler. A column named `[Customer No_]`? Really? A table named `[Company$Cust_ Ledger Entry]`? Really? Somebody needs a real talking to.

Comment: @Lamak SSRS parameter must be text field. User can choose to filter report for 3000 customers. There are ten thousands of possible customer numbers.

Comment: @Rutz a user of a report must write 3000 customer's ids??. If so, at least with a multivalue parameter the can "check" 3000 customers instead

Comment: @AaronBertrand At least it is in English. Adding some Spanish right now might make it interesting!  Naming conventions are totally lacking on this query!

Comment: @Lamak But there are ten thousands of customer numbers. User would have to find the values he wants to check between them. And in my experience - multi-value parameter can handle about 4000 values in multi-choice parameter.

Comment: @Rutz I'm not saying that it's a good choice, just trying to understand the difference between checking thousands of users and writing the same thousands of users separated by a semmicolon

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand Column names are automatically generated from NAV field names, for example Customer No. = [Customer No_] and separated by NAV companies. [CompanyA$Cust_ Ledger Entry], CompanyB$Cust_ Ledger Entry] etc.

Comment: @Lamak I should have mentioned it. User does not writing them. Values are generated from another software.

Comment: Other software is generating large amounts of data and sending it to SSRS - are you sure you are not using the incorrect tool (SSRS) to perform automated integration?

Answer (score 1):

I think  you can simply the query without loss of integrity to the following.  Like Aaron said, can you post a query plan?

```
SELECT  
    DET.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_],
    DET.[Amount],
    DET.[Entry Type],
    CLE.[Document No_]
FROM 
    [dbo].[Company$Cust_ Ledger Entry] CLE
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo].[Company$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] DET 
ON 
    CLE.[Entry No_] = DET.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]
WHERE 
   ( @FAS_No = '' OR DET.[Customer No_] IN (SELECT [No_] FROM Customer) )
   AND DET.[Entry Type] in (1, 2)
   AND CLE.[Due Date] >= @FromDueDate 
   AND CLE.[Due Date] <= @ToDueDate
   AND CLE.[Posting Date] <= @ToDate
```

Comment: Variable @Customer_No takes user input from SSRS. User can choose to filter specific customers or leave it blank (= generate report for all customers).

Comment: That {@FAS_No = '' } is of any use? that @FAS variable is not being used anywhere in the filters, why no just get rid of it?

Comment: Sorry. The FAS_No variable is actually my variable Customer_No. I wanted to make it more obvious, it is number of customer. Gonna edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to pinpoint the exact problem without more information (table structure, # of rows, etc). However, one thing for sure is the the use of OR in TSQL reduces overall performance. If there is a way to use an AND instead of an OR than it's recommended you do so.

what you can always do it use an IF statement that check if the variable is empty. If not, you use the SELECT with the WHERE. If it is empty, you use the SELECT without the WHERE.

Another thing to check might be your indexes. That can speed things a little.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that.  Since it is SSRS, this could be turned into a stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The DET in the where is killing the left so might as well join
If you pull conditions into the join then the query optimizer seems to do a better
I think this gives a the query optimizer a better chance

```
SELECT  DET.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]
      , DET.[Amount]
      , DET.[Entry Type]
      , CLE.[Document No_]
  FROM [dbo].[Company$Cust_ Ledger Entry] CLE
  JOIN [dbo].[Company$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] DET 
    ON CLE.[Entry No_] = DET.[Cust_ Ledger Entry No_]
   AND ( DET.[Entry Type] IN (1,2) )
   AND ( CLE.[Due Date] >= @FromDueDate AND CLE.[Due Date] <= @ToDueDate )
   AND   CLE.[Posting Date] <= @ToDate
  JOIN Customer 
    ON @Customer_No = ''
    OR DET.[Customer No_] = Customer.[No_]
```

And try hints
I would start with INNER MERGE JOIN Customer

And please [NO_] is declared as a PK

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reduce the performance by writing in

- USE CTE for - `(SELECT [No_] FROM Customer)`
- Join cte with the main table which will give you performance